# Does there exist an EBNF-like description of English?

Tags: grammar, linguistics

In programming, languages are often specified by what's called an [EBNF grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBNF), a recursive way of specifying the language's structure. For example, all super simple arithmetic operations using the digits 1-5 can be expressed as

```
  OP = (OP)
  OP = OP + OP
  OP = OP - OP
  OP = OP * OP
  OP = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
```

I was wondering if anyone has attempted a similar description of English or a subset thereof (anything one could wrangle into a computer). For example, I'm sure regular verb conjugation can be thrown into this format, but what about more complex examples? Is there a mathematical proof that one cannot capture the full complexity of English in a finite EBNF grammar?

I am certain this is a complicated question in linguistics, possibly even the holy grail, but I would appreciate any pointers on where to look further!